# how to change name based on activity in model using android

Tags: java, android

I create a model called Review. There are two activities (QualityReivewActivity.java & FairnessReivewActivity.java) will call the model whenever user leaves a comment.
I want to

```
public class Review {
    float fairness_rating; //change the name to quality_rating
    String post_id;
    String review_time;
    String reviewer_id;
    String text_review;


    public Review(){
        //
    }

    Review(float fairness_rating, String post_id, String review_time, String reviewer_id, String text_review){
        this.fairness_rating=fairness_rating;
        this.post_id=post_id;
        this.review_time=review_time;
        this.reviewer_id=reviewer_id;
        this.text_review=text_review;

    }

    public float getFairness_rating() {
        return fairness_rating;
    } //change to getQuality_rating if actitivty is QualityReivewActivity.java

    public String getPost_id() {
        return post_id;
    }

    public String getReview_time() {
        return review_time;
    }

    public String getReviewer_id() {
        return reviewer_id;
    }

    public String getText_review() {
        return text_review;
    }
}
```

and this is the segment of code of QualityReivewActivity

```
Review c = new Review(mRatingBar.getRating(), post_id, timedComment.toString(), reviewer_uid, my_comment.getText().toString()); //
```

However, the QualityReviewActivity always shows "fairness_rating". How can I make a dynamic model name to change to "quality_rating" if I am calling from QualityReviewActivity?

Comment: instead of using fairness_rating , use rating as the variable name.
public float getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

Now based on the value passed from either activity, it will return that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by using enum.

```
public enum ratingType {
　Quality,
　Fairness
}
```

Then use that enum in your function.

```
public float get_rating(ratingType type) {
　switch (type) {
　case Quality:
　　return quality_rating;
　case Fairness:
　　return fairness_rating;
　}
}
```

After that, depending on the class, you can pass the necessary arguments and it will work.

I'm not good at Java, so it may not work if I write it as it is, but the idea is ok.

Comment: Thanks! Also I declare in another class as `Review.ratingType quality = Review.ratingType.quality;` and it works.